# What does the phrase “for the rest of us” mean in this context?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context

Since I’m new to the English language and I have a learning disability and have a difficult time understanding things. I saw a Social Media argument (will give the full conversation to show), and I am hoping that a person breaks down this sentence “At least, that's how you're coming across to the rest of us.” in that argument I’m providing below.

It goes with this:

> Person1: Words are immaterial. How does an Atheist account for words?
> Words have no shape, colour, length or width.
>
> Person2: LOL
>
> Person1: Well?
>
> Person2: It's a moderately funny quip. That's all.
>
> Person1: You still haven’t answered.
>
> Person2: I don't know where to start. First off, you don't know what
> atheism means. I suggest the Oxford English Dictionary as a starting
> point. It doesn't mean you don't believe in immaterial concepts. Of
> course not. I suspect you're a timewaster, though. Have a great day
> and life.
>
> Person1: What are immaterial concepts to an Atheist? I suspect you
> don't know.
>
> Person1: She blocked me. Afraid of the truth I suspect.
>
> And then a third person steps in:
>
> Person3 to Person1: No, pretty sure she blocked you because you were
> responding in bad faith, and being extremely insufferable. **At least,
> that's how you're coming across to the rest of us.** Do better. There
> are a lot of truth lovers who won't put up with your shit, and they
> shouldn't.
>
> Person2 to Person3: I blocked him out of boredom.
>
> Person3: Blocking is such a great feature.

If someone can explain that sentence for me in context of that conversation, that would be great!

Comment: It’s *to*, not *for*. “To come across to” is the phrase you want to consider.

Comment: Rest also has the following definition: noun (OTHER PART), the other things, people, or parts that are left

Comment: "That is the impression you give to all the other people who are following the conversation."

Comment: Generally speaking, a person who says "the rest of us" either knows how everyone else feels, perhaps from having discussed the situation with them back-channel, or by assessing what everyone but you has been saying, or the person simply assumes they have such knowledge of what others are thinking.  The words establish a "you versus us" scenario, whether that is truly the case or not.

Answer (score 1):

> At least, that's how **you're coming across** to the rest of us.

At least, that's **the impression [that] you give** to the rest of us.

OED

> **To come across**
>
> **2.** intransitive. ...**Also more generally: to be perceived in a specified way; to give a specified impression.**
>
> 1917 *Lenine's [sic] particular objection to capitalism in America is
> that it won't come across like capitalism in Germany.* Washington Post
> 21 November 6/3
>
> 1974 *O'Brien comes across as a deeply dedicated party man.*
> Publishers Weekly 5 August 57/1
>
> 1998 *The radio broadcast of the speech came across badly.* M. A.
> Butler, Cautious Visionary 168
>
> 2009 *If Salander had come in..wearing a twin-set and pearls and sensible shoes, she would have came across as a con artist.* ‘R. Keeland’, translation of S. Larsson, Girl who kicked Hornets' Nest xxv. 493

**The rest** of us

**the rest** = the group excluding yourself.

(OED **the rest**: *all the related things/persons, or everything/everyone else of a similar type,*)

Compare

"I will take three of the apples and you can have the rest."